# "Supporting token signatures not expected." error when communicating with Java services from .NET

Tags: java, c#, wcf, x509certificate

I am using .NET WCF to connect to a Java service. This service requires that the message contains a Security header with Timestamp, and a BinarySecurityToken. Effectively, I needed to sign this message with a X509Certificate2.

I achieved this by adding a Service Reference, and having the following endpoint configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
        <bindingElementExtensions>
            <add name="httpsViaProxyTransport" type="MyProject.HttpsViaProxyTransportElement, MyProject"/>
        </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>

    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="HttpsViaProxy">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
                <security authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport" />
                <httpsViaProxyTransport authenticationScheme="Anonymous" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://myservice.com/" binding="customBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="HttpsViaProxy" contract="ServiceReference1.ServiceGateway"
          name="ServiceGateway">
            <identity>
                <dns value="Unknown" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My custom binding "HttpsViaProxyTransportElement" is used to simply allow communication via http as opposed to https.

```
public class HttpsViaProxyTransportBindingElement : HttpTransportBindingElement {

    public override BindingElement Clone() {
        return new HttpsViaProxyTransportBindingElement();
    }

    public override T GetProperty<T>(BindingContext context) {
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(ISecurityCapabilities)){
            return (T)(object)new SslViaProxySecurityCapabilities();
        }
        return base.GetProperty<T>(context);
    }
}

public class SslViaProxySecurityCapabilities : ISecurityCapabilities {
    public System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel SupportedRequestProtectionLevel => System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;

    public System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel SupportedResponseProtectionLevel => System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;

    public bool SupportsClientAuthentication => false;

    public bool SupportsClientWindowsIdentity => false;

    public bool SupportsServerAuthentication => true;
}

public class HttpsViaProxyTransportElement : HttpTransportElement {
    public override Type BindingElementType => typeof(HttpsViaProxyTransportBindingElement);

    protected override TransportBindingElement CreateDefaultBindingElement() {
        return new HttpsViaProxyTransportBindingElement();
    }
}
```

This results in a fairly straight forward call in code:

```
var service = new ServiceReference1.ServiceGateway();
service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;
service.SubmitRequest(request);
```

This generates exactly what is needed for http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd and I get a valid response from the service.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-5A124105B7F7A0216E15324035822311925">
                <wsu:Created>2018-07-24T03:39:42.231Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2018-07-24T03:44:42.231Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-5A124105B7F7A0216E15324035822291924">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="SOAP-ENV"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-5A124105B7F7A0216E15324035822291923">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList=""/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>ZnP0NouGzdrt2E1VSZ3zaP4lmKE=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#SC-5A124105B7F7A0216E15324035822291919">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse SOAP-ENV"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>uVPhFrXfkZo3K2sVkzhc/2DhEis=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>[...]</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-5A124105B7F7A0216E15324035822291921">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-5A124105B7F7A0216E15324035822291922" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Unknown,OU=Unknown,O=Unknown,L=Unknown,ST=Unknown,C=Unknown</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>[...]</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                            </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <wsse11:SignatureConfirmation xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" Value="[...]" wsu:Id="SC-5A124105B7F7A0216E15324035822291919"/>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-5A124105B7F7A0216E15324035822291923">
        [...]
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Some items in the above snippet replaced with [...] to limit verbosity etc.

However this response seems to not be acceptable to the .NET code, as I get the error:

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>Message security verification failed.</ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>
        System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException
    </ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>
        Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
    </StackTrace>
    <InnerException>
        <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
        <ExceptionMessage>Supporting token signatures not expected.</ExceptionMessage>
        <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
        <StackTrace>
            at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ProcessSupportingSignature(SignedXml signedXml, Boolean isFromDecryptedSource) at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ExecuteFullPass(XmlDictionaryReader reader) at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy extendedProtectionPolicy) at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
        </StackTrace>
    </InnerException>
</Error>
```

I am unsure what might be going wrong?

Thanks in advance!